# I have a problem with opening and closing menu on mobile view after clicking on link

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to create a menu in mobile view of a website that im developing.

Im trying to make a function that closes menu after clicking a link.

Link to website:
https://parlourplaces.de/
HTML:

```js
    $(document).on("click",".menu", function(){
      $(".menu").closest(".menu").hide();
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-weight: 500;
}
a,
a:visited,
a:hover,
a:active {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.outer-menu {
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  opacity: 0;
}
.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle:checked + .hamburger > div {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle:checked + .hamburger > div:before,
.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle:checked + .hamburger > div:after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle:checked + .hamburger > div:after {
  opacity: 0;
}
.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle:checked ~ .menu {
  pointer-events: auto;
  visibility: visible;
}
.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle:checked ~ .menu > div {
  transform: scale(1);
  transition-duration: 0.75s;
}
.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle:checked ~ .menu > div > div {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease 0.4s;
}

.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle:checked:hover + .hamburger > div {
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}
.outer-menu .hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 16px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  border-radius: 0 0.12em 0.12em 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.outer-menu .hamburger > div {
  position: relative;
  flex: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background: white;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.outer-menu .hamburger > div:before,
.outer-menu .hamburger > div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -10px;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background: inherit;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.outer-menu .hamburger > div:after {
  top: 10px;
}
.outer-menu .menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.outer-menu .menu > div {
  width: 260vw;
  height: 260vw;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  flex: none;
  transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.outer-menu .menu > div > div {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 90vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.outer-menu .menu > div > div > ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 1em;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  max-height: 100vh;
}
.outer-menu .menu > div > div > ul > li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 1em;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: block;
}
.outer-menu .menu > div > div > ul > li > a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: color 0.4s ease;
}
.outer-menu .menu > div > div > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #adff2f;
}
.switcher {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  margin-top: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-menu">
  <input class="checkbox-toggle" type="checkbox" />
  <div class="hamburger">
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="https://parlourplaces.de/#section-334-22">Wie es funktioniert</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://parlourplaces.de/#section-338-22">Coworking</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://parlourplaces.de/#section-38-22">Unser Studio</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://parlourplaces.de/#section-342-22">Preisgestaltung</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://parlourplaces.de/#section-353-22">Über uns</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://parlourplaces.de/#section-6-22">Kontakt</a></li>
          <center><div class="switcher"><?php echo do_shortcode("[wpml_language_selector_widget]"); ?></div></center>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

At the moment this JS "kind of works". It closes menu, but then the button doesn't work anymore. I assume that the ".menu" is hidden permanently, rest of the classes is still visible.

Any idea how to correct it?

Sorry if I posted code incorrectly, Im a beginner on this forum and overall with CSS and JS, everything seems to be overwhelming to me :/

Thanks in advance for any advice! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to attach an eventlistener to the links themselves and close the menu. You can do this:

```
$(function(){
    $(".menu a").on("click", function(){
        $(".menu").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    });
});
```

Does that do the trick?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately code does exactly the same function as old one. It just disables for good .menu class, so the button doesn't work anymore after first use of menu item links. Also i tried to use both, no luck. Same results.

Comment: Apparently your code uses `visibility:hidden` for the whole `.menu`. I adjusted the code. What you will have to adjust is that the `.menu` remains on the page with `visibility:hidden` and therefore is always in front of the whole page, even if it is not visible to the user.

Comment: If i change to the new code without any additional corrections then it still works exactly like b4. No changes.
Im not sure what do you mean by adjusting '.menu' to ramain on the page with 'visibility:hidden'. It is already with hidden property, or maybe Im not seeing something in CSS?
Also, should i also still add event listeners to links? Can I add them by giving those links a class? Then probably some code in JS referring to those new link classes? I've found this one on W3School: 'document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", myFunction);'.
Will it work?

Comment: See my answer. This is how you add an eventListener to a link: `$(".menu a").on("click", function(){});`